# WCF RIA Services build error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, wcf-ria-services

I'm getting a strange error when building my WCF RIA Services Silverlight project in VS2008. In the output I have this message:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets(261,5): error : Failed to write the generated contents of 'C:\projects\[Path_To_Silverlight_Project]\Generated_Code\Analytics.Web.g.cs' to Visual Studio.
```

...and Visual Studio opens a dialog while building with the following:

```
An editor or project is attempting to save a file that is modified in memory. Saving files during a build is dangerous and may result in incorrect build outputs in the future. Continue with save?
```

The other members on my team seems to be doing just fine, but I can't get past this point (I can if I click 'Continue' which then generate the file just fine but I'm reluclant to do so). There must be some setup or similar that I'm missing here...

PS: I'm currently on WinXP and WCF RIA Service beta

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was generated by the fact that the generated file was on TFS, and when i got the latest version TFS forgot to take this file also. So I went to the Team Explorer, forced TFS to get the file locally and then after a build all worked like a charm.